# Access to com.sun.crypto.provider in Equinox

Tags: encryption, osgi, equinox, classloader

I am trying to integrate some pre-existing code that relies on the
com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE class into our Equinox based
application (version 3.7.1). Now I know by default the com.sun
packages are not accessible to bundles, so I made a fragment with the
idea of extending the framework to export the package. Here is its
manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Extension
Bundle-SymbolicName: extension
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: system.bundle; extension:=framework
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: com.sun.crypto.provider
```

Clue 1: The PDE marks the Export-Package line and says that
com.sun.crypto.provider does not exist in this plugin.

I created a sample bundle that just instantiates the class in question
in the bundle activator. That bundle's manifest is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Cryptotest
Bundle-SymbolicName: cryptotest
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: cryptotest.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: com.sun.crypto.provider,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
```

Clue 2:  The PDE marks the instantiation with an access restriction.

Despite the two errors, the project does compile and I am able to
start debugging. When starting the sample bundle, I receive a class
not found exception. However, when I do a "packages 0" in the console, it appears
Equinox is claiming to export this package:

```
com.sun.crypto.provider;
version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106 [0]>
 cryptotest_1.0.0.qualifier [2] imports
```

Now, I have found an ugly work around that appears to work in my minimal example. It is to basically wrap Java's jce provider jar in a separate plugin and include that with my application, but that just seems wrong.

Could somebody please provide some insight into what's going on? Is
there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a package that is present in your JVM, but only when running on a Sun one. These are not exposed by the system bundle by default, because OSGi is not built solely for Sun VMs.

You can, however, instruct the framework to expose this package. To do so, you set the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` property to a list of packages, which includes your `com.sun.crypto.provider` package. There are several ways to do this, but you could, for instance start Equinox with a system property,

```
-Dorg.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=com.sun.crypto.provider
```

By the way, this is not Equinox-specific, but a standard OSGi-construct.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the option and am still getting the same error. I think it may be due to the fact that when running Equinox, the jce jar is not in the boot path so the vm is not aware that it is available.

Comment: I found a couple of approaches to get this working. 1) using a fragment who's host is bundle 0 and then exporting the package. This worked after modifying the boot path to include the jce jar. 2) Using your suggested cmd line arg in addition to adding the jce jar to the boot path worked as well. I guess a slight downside is this approach exposes the jce to all plugins regardless of whether o r not they import the package. Doesn't affect me, but might be a problem for some? Anyway, accepted answer and +1 for a much simpler solution.

Comment: I wasn't aware this package is not part of the vm by default; it's probably best to nicely wrap the jar in a bundle, that exports the package, in stead of extending the system bundle. My solution essentially brings you back to a regular classpath.